# Paraview. Moving slice plane following a particle

Tags: animation, slice, paraview

My question is:

Is there any way to get a paraview slice plane with origin defined with  a particle's center?. I mean, is there a way to moving the slice plane with the particle?

My idea is to simulate an animation that only shows the slice plane in which lie the particle, as if the slice was tracing the particle's movement.

The only similar thing that I found was [this question](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2010-February/015837.html), but I did not understand what they tried to explain. Also, I am not sure if [this answer](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2010-February/016019.html) solve the problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using the trace option within the gui to essentially save an image at each timestep? Should work.

Comment: I'm able to get a specific slice with the GUI. But my idea is try to set the slice position directly using a file (i.e. a .vtk file). Thereby, I could then through a script fix the slice position and generate an animation. That's is my approach. Do you have another solution?

Comment: If you turn the trace option on in the Tools->Start Trace and then generate your specific slice, do you get coordinates(slice position) in the script? If so, you could back-engineer these in a loop and save a picture every time and then create some sort of gif animation(I usually use Mathematica, it has a nice animate table of images option).

Comment: Great idea. Let me try to implement.

But, could be passed the information associated with the slice in  the same file that have all particle positions (i.e. in the same .vtk file)?

Comment: What "information" do you want from the slice? I know that if you slice it, it will give you the vector normal. What else do you need?

Comment: The only information that I need are origin position and normal. The normal vector I could define with some preferred axis direction. Then, the information that I want to extract from the vtk file is the particle position in order to define properly my slice using only the same datafile.